# GCC scalar_storage_order attribute

Tags: c, gcc, struct, embedded, endianness

In C:

```
struct __attribute__((scalar_storage_order("big-endian"))) test_struct{
int a;
int b;
int c;
};

struct test_struct test1 = {1,1,1};
struct test_struct test2[3] = {{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}};

void func1(int *arg);
void func2(struct test_struct *arg);

int main()
{
    func1(&test1.a);
    func2(&test2[1]);

    return 0;
}

void func1(int *arg){};
void func2(struct test_struct *arg){}
```

The call to func1 results in the GCC (Linux) error "cannot take address of scalar with reverse storage order"
while the call to func2 compiles and executes as expected.

This is just a simple example that demonstrates the issue I've encountered in a much larger code base that can't be posted for proprietary reasons.

The code base is dual target where the targets differ in endianness, hence the scalar_storage_order modification on the big-endian target version. GCC version 8.5.0

I'm struggling to understand how scalar_storage_order works 'under the hood', why can I pass the address of a struct that contains reverse order scalar variable, but I can't pass the address of the reverse scalar variable itself? How does memory get organized to create these 2 conditions?

Comment: _… why can I pass the address of a struct that contains reverse order scalar variable…_ Why not? As long as the _scalar variable_ isn't accessed, it's order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page about endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) tells you some background.

Anyway, in simple words and your case, endianness means the order to store a value that spans several memory cells, here multiple bytes of `int`s.

This is a simple test program, probably non-conforming to the standard:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump(unsigned char *p, size_t l) {
  while (l > 0) {
    printf("%02X", *p);
    p++;
    l--;
  }
  puts("");
}

int main(void) {
  struct __attribute__((scalar_storage_order("big-endian"))) {
    int v;
  } be = { 0x12345678 };
  struct __attribute__((scalar_storage_order("little-endian"))) {
    int v;
  } le = { 0x12345678 };

  dump((unsigned char *)&be, sizeof be);
  dump((unsigned char *)&le, sizeof le);

  return 0;
}
```

On my system (Windows 10 with an older MinGW) this program prints:

```
12345678
78563412
```

So the error reminds you to check the endianness of the referenced value. And as you see from the experiment, it tries to stop you from mis-interpretation. `test1.a` is a value in reverse endianness to the default `int`.

*Note: This attribute is [supported by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html) only for structures and unions and has an effect only on scalar types and arrays there of, and not for all targets.*

Answer (score 0):

I only could deal with this using **unions** and keeping pointers ALWAYS to little endian variables / structs.

```
struct t_Time {
    int  wkup;
    int  pdown;
};

struct t_Others {
    int  Pump;
    int  Valve
};

typedef struct t_Time    __attribute__((scalar_storage_order("big-endian")))  t_TimeBE  ;
typedef struct t_Others  __attribute__((scalar_storage_order("big-endian")))  t_OthersBE;

struct typ_systemLE {               // little endian 
    struct t_Time       Time ;
    struct t_Others     Other;
};

struct typ_systemBE {               // big endian  twin 
     t_TimeBE           Time ;      // w/ big endian structs
     t_OthersBE         Other;
};

union typ_systemU {             // same address for both LE & BE 
    struct typ_systemLE  LE;
    struct typ_systemBE  BE;
};

union typ_systemU System, buff_System; 

#define system          System.BE  // use w/ legacy code

void try (void)
{
    system.Time.wkup = 123456;      //  legacy code unchanged 

    System.BE.Time.wkup = 123456;    // read write through BE (or legacy)
    int * pt = &System.LE.Time.wkup; // pointer access through LE 
}
```

This last step require code change, could be solved w/ some #defines ...